# mcv not returning view if we call method for jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared Layout and on click of a tag it is calling a method and returning a view and content is displayed in the render body section.

The syntax I have used is

`<a class="mng_supplier" href="@Url.Action("GetAllSupplier", "Supplier")">`

It works fine.. But when i was trying call from jquery ajax

```
    var url = Supplier/GetAllSupplier;
    $.post(url, {id: id}, function (response) {
        if (response) {
    // Sucess            }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        alert("Delete Failed");
    });
```

It is calling the same methode and executes the return View line but content was not binding to the page

How to do this?

Comment: You need to add the response to the DOM in the success callback e.g. `$(someElement).html(response);`

Comment: You need to render the view once returned i.e in your `success` function

Comment: Your URL should be like this >>>> var url = /Supplier/GetAllSupplier;

Answer (score 1):

You must use your code like this

```
var url = "/Supplier/GetAllSupplier";
    $.post(url, {id: id}, function (response) {
        if (response) {
        $(document).html(response) 
     }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        alert("Delete Failed");
    });
```

Please mark as answer if it helps u

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$.Ajax({
 url: "/Supplier/GetAllSupplier",
 data: {id: id},
 type: 'POST',
 success: function(response) {
   $(document).html(response); 
 } 
});
```